# uninitialized?, tuitionCost, local Variable,

Tags: c++, variables, local

```
int main()

{
    double tuitionCalc(int sumCreditHoursTaken);

    int numCourses;
    double total = 0.0;
    double tuitionCost= 0.0;


    cout << "\t\t This Program calculates a student's total number of\n";
    cout << "\t\tcredit hours and tution for a given semester.\n";

    cout << "\nPlease enter the number of Courses you will be taking this semester: ";
    cin >> numCourses;

    for ( int count = 1; count <= numCourses; count++)
    {
        double sumCreditHoursTaken;
        cout << " please enter the number of credit hours for course" << count << ": ";
        cin >> sumCreditHoursTaken;
        total += sumCreditHoursTaken;
    }

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Your Total number of credit hours is: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Your total tuition will be: $" << tuitionCalc(tuitionCost) << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

and the function im calling is

```
double tuitionCalc(int sumCreditHoursTaken)
{
    double tuitionCost = 0.0;
    double costCreditHour = 147.00;
    double maxHoursFullTuition = 12;
    double maintFeeAddOn = 29.33;`

    if (sumCreditHoursTaken <= maxHoursFullTuition)
        cout<< " " <<  (sumCreditHoursTaken * costCreditHour);
    else if (sumCreditHoursTaken > maxHoursFullTuition)
        cout << " " << (maxHoursFullTuition * costCreditHour) + ((sumCreditHoursTaken - maxHoursFullTuition) * maintFeeAddOn);

    return tuitionCost;
}
```

input for number of courses is 5
and credit hours is 3,3,3.5,4,2.5
i get the total credit hours but icant seem to display the tuition cost?
thank you s

Comment: You have called the "tuitionCalc" function for a parameter (tuitionCost=0) which is zero.

Comment: @user26456166 see the answer I coded

Comment: thanks i understand the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You are never actually assigning a value to `tuitionCost` in `tuitionCalc()` method, so it will always be `0.0`.

To elaborate: You are returning `tuitionCost` from `tuitionCalc()`. You first initialize `tuitionCost = 0.0`, but never proceed to assign any calculated value to it. Thus, when you return `tuitionCost`, it will return the value you initialized it to: `0.0`.

Comment: could you elaborate more on that ?

Comment: Not much to be elaborated on there. `tuitionCost` shows up twice in the `tuitionCalc` function. First where it is set to 0.0 and the second time when it is returned. `tuitionCost` is never set to anything else, so the function will always return 0.0.

Comment: elaborated a bit, basically what user4581301 said

Answer (score 0):

I haven't examined your code in detail, but if you inputs contain floating point numbers then change the type for sumCreditHoursTaken from int to double.

Also, change the parameter for the invocation of tuitionCalc from *tuitionCost* to *total*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OP has fallen afoul of misunderstanding scope and how variables are passed to functions.

In `main`, OP defines `tuitionCost`. `tuitionCalc` defines another `tuitionCost`. These are different `tuitionCost`s. They represent different locations in memory and can store different values.

Next, because the `tuitionCalc` function is defined

```
double tuitionCalc(int sumCreditHoursTaken)
```

`tuitionCalc(tuitionCost)` will take `tuitionCost` convert it to an integer, and pass a **copy** into `tuitionCalc` where it will be used with the name `sumCreditHoursTaken`. One could say OP has three `tuitionCalc`s at this point. Not what they want.

Breaking down the `tuitionCalc` prototype, we see that it takes `sumCreditHoursTaken`, an integer and based on the name the number of credit hours taken, not a total cost. `tuitionCalc` also returns a `double` and inferring the purpose of the function from it;'s name, one would expect that it calculates and returns the tuition.

Like Anatoly states in his answer, the input to `tuitionCalc` should almost certainly be `total`, the total number of credit hours computed, and the output should be `tuitionCost`.

Since this has the smell of a homework assignment, it's not in the OP's best interests to fully answer the question. Instead here are a few recommendations:

Eliminate `tuitionCost` from `main`. It only serves to increase confusion. You can reuse variable names, but only do it where there is a clear benefit. If you have a `cost` and a function that takes and uses `cost`, then using `cost` for both makes sense. Just remember that cost inside the function is a different entity unless you pass by reference. In

```
void function(int & cost)
```

called with

```
function(cost);
```

both `cost`s are the same. But in

```
void function(int cost)
```

called with

```
function(cost);
```

both `function`'s cost is a copy of the caller's `cost` and any changes made by function will only effect the copy.

Declare variables close to where you use them. This way people reading your code don't have to scroll up and down and otherwise go hunting. It also helps you because it makes mistakes like, "Why am a calling a function that takes an `int` with a `double`?" more obvious.

Do not `cout` in `tuitionCalc`. Compute and return `tuitionCost`. Allow `main` to output `tuitionCost`. A function with a name like `calc` should only calculate. Names should describe function as closely as possible.

Comment: I'm learning c++ online , im not a college student , just learning online , I don't have to turn in no assignment ,it's not a class but thanks for your feed back, my goal was to get to the point of where I messed up

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create the function prototype before declaring it.
And there were some confusions in the code you have used I tried my best to omit error hope this is helpful!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
double tuitionCal(double sumCreditHoursTaken);

int main() {

     double tuitionCalc(int sumCreditHoursTaken);

    int numCourses;
    double total = 0.0;
    //double tuitionCost= 0.0;


    cout << "\t\t This Program calculates a student's total number of\n";
    cout << "\t\tcredit hours and tution for a given semester.\n";

    cout << "\nPlease enter the number of Courses you will be taking this semester: ";
    cin >> numCourses;

    double sumCreditHoursTaken; // you should create this variable outside the for loop

    for ( int count = 1; count <= numCourses; count++)
    {
        cout << " please enter the number of credit hours for course" << count << ": ";
        cin >> sumCreditHoursTaken;
        total += sumCreditHoursTaken;
    }

    double tuitionCost=tuitionCal(total);
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Your Total number of credit hours is: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Your total tuition will be: $" <<tuitionCost<< "\n\n";// I assume this is what you want



    return 0;
}

double tuitionCal(double sumCreditHoursTaken)//the parameter type is double now
{
    double tuitionCost = 0.0;
    double costCreditHour = 147.00;
    double maxHoursFullTuition = 12;
    double maintFeeAddOn = 29.33;

    if (sumCreditHoursTaken <= maxHoursFullTuition)
        tuitionCost=(sumCreditHoursTaken * costCreditHour);
    else if (sumCreditHoursTaken > maxHoursFullTuition)
       tuitionCost=(maxHoursFullTuition * costCreditHour) + ((sumCreditHoursTaken - maxHoursFullTuition) * maintFeeAddOn);

    return tuitionCost;
    //I don't see a point of returning the value and couting both you can 
    //do only one of the oprations
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the first line in `main` for the function prototype. Odd place to put it, but still legal. Personally I like to do away with prototypes where possible by placing the definition ahead of use. One less possible source of error.

Comment: Recommendations: Turn `costCreditHour` and friends into constants. `sumCreditHoursTaken` should have stayed an `int` and `costCreditHour` should be an `int`. `double` comparisons can get weird due to floating point imprecision. `else if` can just be `else`. If the test for `<=` fails, only `>` is left.